# Error When Trying To Pick A contact and Show its Number in a TextBox in Android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

First of all sorry for my Bad English
i'm new To Android development.
I'm trying to develop this App in which user can click on a button and the Contacts will show up and then can pick one and only one one of the Contacts and show its number in a textbox.
But i face this Error every time :

> "Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor
>   is initialized correctly before accessing data from it"

and The Funny thing is when i use **HAS_PHONE_NUMBER** it returns **1** which means the Contact has Phone Number.
and when i use **DISPLAY_NAME** it returns contact name without any problem.
but when i use **NUMBER** that Error shows Up!
can anyone help me?
BTW i use Fragment if it helps..?
and this is my code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnContact) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);        }

}


private Uri uriContact;
private String contactID; // contacts unique ID





@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor phone = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                phone.moveToFirst();

                if (phone.moveToFirst()) {
                    String num = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    // Todo something when contact number selected
                    placeholderNumber.setText("" + num);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, this is the second time *today* that i answer this exact question. you should use a "phone picker" not a "contact picker" for this use-case, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47271920/819355

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a Specific Contact's phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270941/how-to-import-a-specific-contacts-phone-number)

Comment: @marmor
tnx Bro thats really Funny Exaactly some One asked the same Question as mine at the Same Time :)))))
tnx BTW

Comment: sure thing, can you please then confirm this question is a duplicate and close it, so it'll keep StackOverflow nice and clean?